# What is Issur Moisef?

Tags: talmud-gemara, sin

What is Issur Moisef I heard two people talking about this concept in the context of "AIN ISSUR CHAL AL ISSUR" please illustrate with example?

Comment: I do not think it is possible to un-slang this question but if someone feels they can please do?

Comment: Where do you find this term in connection with קם ליה בדרבה מיניה? The latter simply means that the death penalty overrides the monetary obligation, and AFAIK it doesn't really matter for this purpose whether the former is an איסור מוסיף relative to the latter, or whether they have exactly the same scope.

Comment: Slang or not, you could improve the question a great deal by providing context. Where is this question coming from?

Comment: alex your right I meant to write "AIN ISSUR CHAL AL ISSUR"

Comment: Issac i dont really have context thats part of what I am looking for

Comment: Chalutzhanal, did these phrases come to you in a dream? Did you see them written on a Bazooka Joe cartoon? Where did you encounter them?

Comment: I heard two people talking and I look over what gemara they where looking at

Comment: So please add to your question something like "I heard two people talking about these concepts. They were learning Baba Maiseh 32b. Now, I'm curious about what these terms mean in that context. Could you help me?" That will make the question more answerable, a better springboard for discussion, and more interesting.

Comment: i did not get a page and they had a shulchan aruch too

Comment: now it has done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in Kiddushin 77b, where the idea of Isur Mosif is discusses in the context of forbidden relationships.

The discussion is if something is forbidden one way, can it become forbidden through a second way. There are two ways to do this:

1. Issur Chal al issur: if something is forbidden twice, so be it. An example is a woman who was a divorcee, widow, challalah and zomah lived with a Kohen Gadol, he is liable 4 times.
2. Issur Moisef: a prohibition could add strength only if it is "more prohibited" then it was before. For example, a Kohen Gadol who lives with a widow who became a divorcee is punished twice. If he lived with a divorcee who became a widow he is punished once.

Comment: Please explain #1. Why wouldn't this be a contradiction of the general principle that something cannot be prohibited for two reasons (i.e. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9893/1516 )?